# Ecommerce Android is not shown in analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, e-commerce

After reading all threads I still haven't figured out why my Android app is not sending the ecommerce values to analytics. (or maybe it does but it is not shown)
I did activate ecommerce in GA, I use v2 and added the following code on orderComplete :

```
GoogleAnalytics ga = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(ctx); 

Transaction cardTransaction = new Transaction.Builder(
  String.valueOf(order.getOrderId()),                   // (String) Transaction Id, should be unique. 
  orderTotal                                            // (long) Order total (in micros)
  .setAffiliation(cardName)                             // (String) Affiliation
  .setTotalTaxInMicros(0)                               // (long) Total tax (in micros)
  .setShippingCostInMicros(0)                           // (long) Total shipping cost (in micros)
  .setCurrencyCode("EUR")                               // (String) Setting the correct currency
  .build();

cardTransaction.addItem(new Item.Builder(
  caption,                                              // (String) Product SKU (stock-keeping unit)
  productName,                                          // (String) Product name
  price,                                                // (long) Product price (in micros)
  quantity)                                             // (long) Product quantity
  .setProductCategory(productCategorie)                     // (String) Product category 
  .build());

Tracker tracker = ga.getTracker(R.string.googleAnalyticsKey);

tracker.sendTransaction(cardTransaction); // Send the transaction.
GAServiceManager.getInstance().dispatch();
```

I logged all values and they are correct and in the correct format.

Can anyone explain where I make a mistake?

Comment: ga.getTracker(R.string.googleAnalyticsKey) is wrong. You need to pass the resolved string. So its rather ga.getTracker(getString(R.string.googleAnalyticsKey));